# How to run different while loops without breaking any

Tags: c++, windows, qt, loops, qthread

How to run two different `while` loops without breaking one?

The program does two different collects of values from a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller) via `while` loop.

And this collects should be at the **same time**, but when I try to run both of the loops, they break... The first loop simply stop returning any value, while the second one is running.

Comment: use multiple threads.......

Comment: Nothing should block the gui thread. Sleeps are a big no no, use QTimer for polling tasks.Heavy processing must either be done in a separate thread or you should break it into smallish chunk and defer to later. QTimer can take a zero time if you want to defer tasks.

Comment: About multiple threads @eyllanesc , I already "create" a QThread, so theoretically the MainProgram is running into the MainThread and the infinite loop is running on the secondary QThread...

Comment: And about QTimer @doron, Yeah, I totally agree with you, but even reading documents I can't understand how to use QTimer...

Comment: Please note that your Question is currently being closed for lacking debugging details. if you could make the examples so that anyone can reproduce them, perhaps your HowTo Question can be better answered.

Comment: Dear @Scratte , how can I create examples to anyone reproduce, if the program NEED a especific PLC?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know that. Perhaps you can give details as which specific one your code needs? If you say that your code behaves in a specific say under specific circumstances, then maybe give details about those?

Comment: The code needs a PLC GP3K 3210 by BCM Automações (from Brazil)

Comment: Oh!. Can this be reproduced by another one? Or.. can it be simulated by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program needs to connect, read and disconnect from two devices, however, it can only have one connection open at a time. Thus, the connections are mutually exclusive. You could use a mutex for that.

Your code suggests, that one connection should be polled indefinitely with a certain timeout, and the other on request via a button. I would simply put both in a slot, one called by the button, the other by a timer, and protect them with a mutex.

Outline:

```
class MainProgram : QObject {
    // Other stuff
private slots:
    void on_pushCheck_clicked();
    void readPeriodically();
    
private:
    QMutex m_mutex;
    QTimer *m_timer;
};

void MainProgram::MainProgram()
{
    // other stuff

    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainProgram::readPeriodically);
    m_timer->setInterval(2000);
    m_timer->start();
}

void MainProgram::on_pushCheck_clicked()
{
    QMutexLocker l(&m_mutex);
    
    // Read from device 1
}

void MainProgram::readPeriodically()
{
    QMutexLocker l(&m_mutex);
    
    // Read from device 2
}
```

This assumes that reading will be very quick, as the UI is blocked during this time. If that is not the case, you can put the reading code into a backtround worker thread. This approach is asynchronous, you trigger the read, and the the result some time later:

```
class DeviceReader : QObject {
public:
    void readDevice1();
    void readDevice2();
    
signals:
    void device1Data(int);
    void device2Data(int);
    
private:
    Q_INVOKABLE void doReadDevice1();
    Q_INVOKABLE void doReadDevice2();
    
private:
    QMutex m_mutex;
};

void DeviceReader::readDevice1()
{
    // Cross thread boundary
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "doReadDevice1", Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void DeviceReader::doReadDevice1()
{
    QMutexLocker l(&m_mutex);
    
    // Read from device 1
    
    emit device1Data(1);
}

// similar for device 2


MainProgram::MainProgram() {
    DeviceReader *r = new DeviceReader;
    QThread *t = new QThread;
    
    r->moveToThread(t);

    // Connect signals for starting reads, or call them as necessary
    // Connect signal to deleteLater on thread when app closes
    // e.g. QApplication::aboutToQuit

    // The worker object does not have a "working" method.
    // It will just listen to events (signals) through the thread's exec loop
    t->start();
    
}
```

Comment: The only thing that I dont understand on your code, is how to loop the process... According with your first suggestion @king_nak

Comment: The timer will call the slot every 2 seconds. There is no explicit loop. To connect signals to the thread: similar to what you did in your original post, e.g. `connect(qApp, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, m_thread, &QObject::deleteLater);`